# Use Glyphicons in pagetree nodes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages

I am not sure if this is possible or not while using the bootstrap4xpages extension library. Can you use glyphs as pagetreenode labels or in some way have the glyph show, or am I limited to text if I want to use pagetreenodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the page tree nodes are text only. There are a few options you could look at:

- overwrite the renderer to change the output of the control (most difficult)
- use client side script to add the glyphs. You would spec the class for the whole pagetreenode (styleClass) and then find that classes, remove them and add a span with that class

Not pretty - but possible

Comment: Well, I guess that answers that. Thanks. I guess I will have to think about not using page tree nodes.